# Textarea CSS IE7 and "enter key" creating inline space

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, textarea

Under ie7 i have a strange problem on textareas.
When i type something in and push enter a space seems to be added instead if making a new line.

It seems to be CSS related since when i remove Javascript  the bug is still there.
And when i remove CSS it works as expected.

When i remove all mentions of textarea in my styling the bug does not disappear.
SO maybe its a parent styling of something more complex.

All hints are welcome

http://g.imagehost.org/download/0038/textarea_bug

Here is the file

http://www.2shared.com/file/5302450/2f33f63c/page.html

**Click on the bottom right link to "download the zip"**

Comment: Can you provide some sample code? I can't really determine the cause from your description.

Comment: Please provide us with a sample of the CSS you use, thanks!

Comment: I just added the file, the problem persists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem seems to be your reset styles. Text area has white-space:normal, which apparently IE7 doesn't like.

Put this tag just under your reset line.  I tested this in IE7 and chrome.

```
textarea { white-space:pre; }
```

Comment: nice one, beat me to it in 5 secs... I'll remove my answer and +1 you.

Comment: The reset was probably designed for ie6, which ignores white-space:normal. Since IE7 fixed that bug, the reset needs to be updated.

Comment: This also fixes IE6 textareas returned to nyroModal windows.  Arrrrrgh!